# In bash, how to sort strings including numbers?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have a script that outputs file paths (via find) :

```
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3-something16
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something1
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2-something5
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something2
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something10
```

How can I list them in Bash so that they are in ascending numeric order based on the number at the end and regardless of the version ( 1.2, 1.2.3 or 1.2.3.4)

Ps : the `something` part can eventually contain a dash.

Desired output :

```
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something1
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something2
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2-something5
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something10
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3-something16
```

I used a temporary sentinel character to delimit the number at the end but it's a little bit complicated in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract the number at the end, prepend it to all the lines, sort numerically and finally delete that number:

```
sed -r 's/(.*)([^0-9])([0-9]+)$/\3\1\2\3/' file | sort -n | sed 's/^[0-9]*//'
```

With your input, this returns:

```
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something1
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something2
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2-something5
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something10
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3-something16
```

I think this is the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

---

By pieces:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*)([^0-9])([0-9]+)$/\3\1\2\3/' a
16/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3-something16
1/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something1
5/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2-something5
2/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something2
10/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something10
#^
#note the numbers here

$ sed -r 's/(.*)([^0-9])([0-9]+)$/\3\1\2\3/' a | sort -n 
1/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something1
2/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something2
5/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2-something5
10/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something10
16/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3-something16
                                                  # ^
                                                  # now it is ordered

$ sed -r 's/(.*)([^0-9])([0-9]+)$/\3\1\2\3/' a | sort -n | sed 's/^[0-9]*//'
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something1
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something2
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2-something5
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something10
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3-something16
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `sed + sort + awk`:

```
sed -E 's/.*[^0-9]([0-9]+)$/\1 &/' file | sort -n | awk '{print $2}'

/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something1
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something2
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2-something5
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3.4-something10
/foo/bar/example/foo/bar/example/foo-bar-example/1.2.3-something16
```

Comment: Cool! This is more concise, well done. Probably worth putting the number in the beginning for the case the path contains spaces, and then say `cut -d ' ' -f2-` to print from the 2nd field.

Answer (score 1):

If you can ensure that you will never have a '#' character in your file, you can try:

```
sed -e 's/something/#/g' filename.txt | sort -t# -k2 -n | sed -e 's/#/something/g'
```